# Finding Euler Path without 2 odd degrees?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

![image]https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5ybtns0qd7t4b4/s.png?dl=0

Give an example of a Eulerian Path of the graph that starts at A

Isn't the graph Eulerian if it has 2 odd number of degrees?
when i counted the degrees they were all 4 so how do calculate the eulerian path?

Comment: When all vertices are even, you can even get an Euler cycle — a closed Euler path. That means that you can start anywhere.

Comment: Are Euler cycles and Euler Circuits the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they are; both terms are used.

Comment: Could you give an example of a Euler path based on this graph starting from A? I understand the circuit but not how to get a path from this graph

Comment: A circuit *is* a path; it just happens to finish at a vertex adjacent to its starting point.

Comment: @ASoni Give me an example of an Euler circuit in that graph, and I'll give you an example of an Euler path.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from A. At each step, don't go to any vertex you have visited before until you have visited them all.  You will have an Eulerean path.  If you then return to A, you will have an Eulerean circuit.  On a complete graph with and odd number of vertices, you can't miss.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $G$ has all even-degree vertices. Pick any two vertices that are connected and remove the edge. Then the resulting graph has exactly two odd-degree vertices, so it has an Euler path. That path must begin at one of the odd-degree vertices and end at the other, so adding the edge back in, we can continue the path from one of those vertices back to the other. Thus if $G$ has all even-degree vertices, we get an Euler *cycle*, while if it has two odd-degree vertices, we get only a path.